# javascript code not working as expected inside jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to block browser back button using javascript. It is working fine for sample application, but when I am putting the code in my jsp file, it is not giving the expected behavior and allowing navigate to back page.

Here is the javascript code :

```
window.history.forward();

function noBack(){

      alert("back space code executed...");
      window.history.forward();
}
```

and I am calling above code in JSP inside  tag on **onLoad** event :

```
<body class="jspcheck" onload="noBack()">
```

Interestingly, whenever page opens, the alert comes, but back button was yet not disabled.

I have also tried to call this function using jquery but didn't got expected behavior :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     noBack();
});
```

Any help/pointers for this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: Simply calling `window.history.forward()` will not disable the "Back" button.

Comment: it is working if I use this code in simple HTML/jsp application. it seems that other jquery/js code is overriding my js code. is there anyway so that my js code execute every time page opens?

Comment: I don't think it is actually working in your simple application unless the simple application is actually doing something entirely different.

Comment: @Pointy so can you please suggest what else i can use to disable the back button of browser..?

Comment: @Pointy - I have tried another code also but it also not working :      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function DisableBackButton() {
window.history.forward()
}
DisableBackButton();
window.onload = DisableBackButton;
window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) DisableBackButton() }
window.onunload = function() { void (0) }
</script>

Comment: You can't do it in javascript. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't block the backbutton in a webapplication, period. But I would imagine you are trying to do this to prevent some sql update statement from being run again if someone clicks back. The proper way to prevent that is to always redirect to another page after database updates using your serverside language. Then when the user clicks back, the redirect always kicks in preventing them from going back to the page that did the update.

```
 response.sendRedirect("somepage.jsp");
```

Also, since your serverside code will execute before any javascript anyway, javascript is no good if you need to prevent this kind of thing.